# ReactJS Child Component Not Updating When Props Changes

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to ReactJS, doing some practice, this is my code. When I click the "Show Progress" button, I expect the `Progress` to be triggered by `setInterval` and display the latest time, but it didn't work that way. It just display the value 
 passed in the first time and stay there unchanged.

```
class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.showProgress = this.showProgress.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            now: new Date(),
            content: null
        };
        this.timerId = null;
    }

    showProgress(){
        let content = <Progress now={ this.state.now } />;
        this.setState({ content: content });
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.timerId = setInterval(()=>this.setState({now: new Date()}), 500);
    }

    componentWillUnmount(){
        clearInterval(this.timerId);
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={ this.showProgress }>Show Progress</button>
                { this.state.content }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

function Progress(props){
    return (
        <h2>{ props.now.toString() }</h2>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

If instead embed the `<Progress now={this.state.now}>` into `App`'s `render` logic, then the time get refreshed by `setInterval`.

I wonder what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

You are storing a component in state. I'm not even 100% sure if that works.

Can't you do something like the following?

```
class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.showProgress = this.showProgress.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            now: new Date(),
            content: null,
            showProgress: false,
        };
        this.timerId = null;
    }

    showProgress(){
        this.setState({ showProgress: true });
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.timerId = setInterval(()=>this.setState({now: new Date()}), 500);
    }

    componentWillUnmount(){
        clearInterval(this.timerId);
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={ this.showProgress }>Show Progress</button>
                {this.state.showProgress && <Progress now={ this.state.now } />}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

function Progress(props){
    return (
        <h2>{ props.now.toString() }</h2>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```